# TRY CATCH not working when exception is raised from SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

So, for some reason my TRY CATCH is not capturing the exception thrown by SQL server stored procedure.
Basically, I execute a procedure and it does what it needs or raises an error. This error needs to be captured and raised in the VB app.
What am I doing wrong? And yes, SQL does throw an error...

```
    Public Function InsertDetails(ByVal dBillingDate As Date) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = True
    Try
        CleanUp(ObjCmd)
        ObjCmd = UpgradeHelpers.DB.AdoFactoryManager.GetFactory().CreateCommand()

        ObjCmd.CommandText = "usp_InsAfterHours"
        ObjCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ObjCmd.CommandTimeout = 0
        ObjCmd.Connection = SQLServerDB

        'Get the parameters from the sproc
        ParametersHelper.DeriveParameters(ObjCmd, UpgradeHelpers.DB.AdoFactoryManager.GetFactory())

        With ObjCmd.Parameters
            ObjCmd.Parameters(1).Value = dBillingDate
        End With

        ObjCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()

        Do While ObjCmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Executing
            LoopSet = ""
        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (TypeOf ex Is OleDb.OleDbException) Then
            RaiseError(DirectCast(ex, OleDb.OleDbException).ErrorCode, Me.GetType().Name & ".InsertDetails", ex, DirectCast(ex, OleDb.OleDbException).Errors, g.sDatabaseUserName)
        Else
            RaiseError(CInt(ex.HResult), Me.GetType().Name & ".InsertDetails", ex, , g.sDatabaseUserName)
        End If

        bReturn = False

    Finally 
        CleanUp(ObjCmd)
        result = bReturn
    End Try

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Have the sproc output the error and/or error code and handle the return value.

Comment: But I shouldn't need to do that. That is what TRY CATCH is for. To catch the exceptions thrown by SQL... Do you see anything odd in my code that would not trigger the CATCH?

Comment: Are you using RAISEERROR in your SQL and what is the severity value?

Comment: Yes, we use RAISEERROR in all sprocs with severity level 16.

Answer (score 2):

A few changes I'd recommend:

You aren't waiting for the function to complete:

```
 await ObjCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()
```

Then remove the loop that's doing the checking.

Instead of RaiseError, use the command to throw the Exception.

```
Throw new ApplicationException(Me.GetType().Name & ".InsertDetails", ex)
```

Your caller code can then use the ex.GetBaseException() to get information such as the list of errors, assuming the ex.GetBaseException().Type is an Ole Exception

Ideally, you want to use System.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.OleDb for objects connecting to SQL Server in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you. I can change the RaiseError to Throw, but the problem still remains that the CATCH is not even executed. It goes directly to FINALLY even thou I know an error is thrown by procedure. If I execute the procedure in Management Studio, I can see the error...

Comment: have you set a breakpoint...are you sure its not getting in there and then another error is occurring inside the catch?

Comment: Yes, I step thru every line. After the ObjCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() done executing it goes directly to FINALLY.

Comment: What's the proc and where r u getting the error in the process?

Comment: Here is the proc code. It falls into the first error because there are some empty Cost Centers. But I notice this same behavior all around the application with other procs as well when an error is returned.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsAfterHours
(
  @BillDate smalldatetime
)
AS

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM tmpAgent24 a
    WHERE ISNULL(a.CostCenter,'') = ''
    OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM tblClient c (NOLOCK)
        WHERE c.ClientCode = a.CostCenter))
 BEGIN
  RAISERROR ('Empty or invalid client code exists. Please audit the client codes before import.', 16, 1)
  RETURN
 END

 INSERT INTO aTable
 SELECT aColumns
 RETURN
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON usp_InsAfterHours TO Travel_Group
GO`

Comment: Have u run the proc in management studio...do u know the error is actually being raised?

Comment: Is also very odd you have a parameter you aren't using which makes me suspicious

Comment: Yes, I see the error in management studio. And not sure what you mean by parameter not used. I am using the parameter when executing the statement. I assign all my parameters first and then execute... If you mean in the procedure, I am using it later in procedure. I just had to strop some code off to be able to post it. Too many characters. :)